# How to disable inbound only SSH connections via Group Policy?

Tags: windows, ssh, group-policy

I need to disable SSH inbound only connections on some machines running Windows 10.
As of now, I've only found out how to disable SSH altogether but these machines still need to be able to SSH into other machines. I need to apply this through Group Policy.

Any advice?

Comment: Block port 22 for incoming connections in the Windows firewall?

Comment: @Robert I need to do this via Group Policy as it needs to be applied to a whole network. It's opened on multiple ports and not just on port 22.

Comment: Your question does say nothing about group policies. Please edit your question and add those details you forgot to add.

Comment: @Robert I have updated my question